# Auto resize and position of UIviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad, uiview

Is it possible for Xode to automatically resize and position UIviews within a given frame? I would like it to be done with animations. I would be able to do this manually and just change the frame with an animation of course, but is this the only method?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgaLP.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide/show some views in different conditions you must use code to do it. But if you just want to want the Xcode to help you automatically resize and position UIViews within a given frame, you can try this in Xcode's size inspector->constraints.

Comment: I can manage to hide/show through code, but can I do contrains to other subviews?

Comment: What do you mean by "do contrains to other subviews"?

Comment: I want the views to always share all the available screen space with each other, but I generate the UIviews through code and I can set it up with constraints in IB. That is why I sort of need a solution which will find the closet element (either other UIView or edge of screen) and make a constraint to lets say 5px from it.

Comment: So I have a dynamic amount of UIviews. Is it clear what I want here?

Comment: It's clear and I have tried but can't find a good way through Xcode, sorry. I think code is the best way for your problem. Wait for expert to solve this question.